How to improve xml parsing performance
I have a large xml which contain many records as child elements. There are many test elements and inside each test element many testchild elements. There are around 200 elements or 300 or more. As all attributes of these elements are not coming from the xml file, I need to manually parse the xml elements and convert it into list of objects. This is taking a long time (around 46 seconds) which is very lengthy.
How can I improve the performance? I am using foreach to iterate. I tried linq also, but it takes about the same amount of time. I can't use AsParallel().All because it is crashing when some elements are not filled by the time.
Could you help me in improving performance? It is in C#.
<root>
  <test>
    <testchild>
    </testchild>
    <testchild>
    </testchild>
  </test>
  <test>
    <testchild>
    </testchild>
    <testchild>
    </testchild>
  </test>
</root>


what code are you currently using? parsing 200/300 elements should take about 1ms...

I would write an example using XmlSerializer, but your xml is invalid (multiple root elements) - but something like https://gist.github.com/mgravell/46d975abbd4f442e699d9046ab15d3ae

I cant use deserialize bcos some attributes are filled manually an deserialize need all attributes to be in class. Other attributes are created dynamically. So I am parsing each element and its descendants and filling values into list of object

there are ways of handling that (starting with, but not limited to, [XmlAnyAttribute] and [XmlAnyElement] or the UnknownAttribute / UnknownElement events); a pre-rolled serializer is going to be a lot better at this than anything you write; again, this should take nanoseconds, or maybe milliseconds for a particularly large/complex model


Could you help me in improving performance? It is in C#.

Without code? No. Show some code, and we might stand a chance.
However, XmlSerializer is going to be much better at this than you. Serialization looks simple from the outside, but there are lots of edge cases and pitfalls, and avoiding those while maintaining performance is hard.
But: a model of 200/300 elements should be basically instant; if it is taking 46 seconds, either there is something horribly wrong in your code that I can't speculate about (please show code if you want input here!), or: you're processing a few GiB of data.
Here's a runnable example that caters to your basic model while also supporting the unknown attributes/elements alluded to in the comments:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

var xml = """
    <root>
      <test>
        <testchild>
        </testchild>
        <testchild>
        </testchild>
      </test>
      <test>
        <testchild id="42" name="fred">
        </testchild>
        <testchild>
        </testchild>
      </test>
    </root>
    """;

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyRoot));
var obj = (MyRoot)serializer.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))!;
Console.WriteLine(obj.Tests.Sum(x => x.Children.Count));
Console.WriteLine(obj.Tests[1].Children[0].GetAttribute("id"));

[XmlRoot("root")]
public class MyRoot
{
    [XmlElement("test")]
    public List<MyTest> Tests { get; } = new();
}
public class MyTest
{
    [XmlElement("testchild")]
    public List<MyChild> Children { get; } = new();
}

public class MyChild {
    public string? GetAttribute(string name)
        => attributes?.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name)?.Value;
    public string? GetElement(string name)
        => elements?.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name)?.Value;

    private List<XmlElement>? elements;
    private List<XmlAttribute>? attributes;

    [XmlAnyAttribute]
    public List<XmlAttribute> Attributes => attributes ??= new();
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public List<XmlElement> Elements => elements ??= new();
}


I will try out and will let you know. Thanks for helping
